# Experimenting with Pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, cs50

I'm new to coding and started my journey about a month ago. I just completed Problem Set 4 for CS50 but wanted to play around a bit with pointers. Regarding Academic Honesty - I already submitted this problem, this is just a different version of it.

This is a reflection filter, to mirror the image RGBTRIPLE contains the colors red, green and blue for each pixel in the image.
For each row, this should swap the pixels on horizontally opposite sides. Repeat for every row in the photo.

I'm trying to figure out if I can use pointers to solve the problem but it seems to not work. Wouldn't this way just swap the the address of the first pixel with the address of the last? Is it even possible to solve it this way? Again, already submitted this specific set, just want to understand pointers betters in action and if there's a way to do it with the help of them. Thank you for your help!

```
// Reflect image horizontally
   void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)

    for (int j = 0; j < width / 2; j++)

        // find color values for first pixel
        int first_red = image [i][j].rgbtRed;
        int* pfirst_red = &first_red;

        int first_green = image [i][j].rgbtGreen;
        int* pfirst_green = &first_green;

        int first_blue = image [i][j].rgbtBlue;
        int* pfirst_blue = &first_blue;

        // find color values for last pixel
        int last_red = image[i][width - j - 1].rgbtRed;
        int* plast_red = &last_red;

        int last_green = image[i][width - j - 1].rgbtGreen;
        int* plast_green = &last_green;

        int last_blue = image[i][width - j - 1].rgbtBlue;
        int* plast_blue = &last_blue;
        
        // Convert first pixel to last
        pfirst_red = &last_red;
        pfirst_green = &last_green;
        pfirst_blue = &last_blue;

        // Convert last pixel to first
        plast_red = &first_red;
        plast_green = &first_green;
        plast_blue = &first_blue;


        
        :( reflect correctly filters 1x2 image
           expected "0 0 255\n255 0...", not "255 0 0\n0 0 2..."
        :( reflect correctly filters 1x3 image
           expected "0 0 255\n0 255...", not "255 0 0\n0 255..."
        :) reflect correctly filters image that is its own mirror image
        :( reflect correctly filters 3x3 image
           expected "70 80 90\n40 5...", not "10 20 30\n40 5..."
        :( reflect correctly filters 4x4 image
           expected "100 110 120\n7...", not "10 20 30\n40 5..."
```

Comment: `pfirst_red = &last_red;` All the `pfirst_` variables are local pointers. Changing them does not in any way change the content of what they are pointing to. You need something like `*pfirst_red = *last_red;`

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) then the documentation of your C compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (maybe [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and http://frama-c.com/ .... Look for inspiration on existing code on http://github.com/

Comment: Provide some [mre] in your next question, and compile your code with all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would check the declaration of `RGBTRIPLE`, as its members could have a size which is not `int`. When using pointers of incorrect size neighboring variables will be overwritten and corrupt the code.

I found this one on google but check your environment.

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
}
RGBTRIPLE;
```

In your code, besides having a pointer to an item of incorrect size, you declare a local variable and then pointing to is address.

```
int last_red = image[i][width - j - 1].rgbtRed;
int* plast_red = &last_red;   // plast_red is a pointer to last_red
```

This will only let you swap values for your local variables.

You should get the address from the data within the structure instead:

```
RGBTRIPPLE* ptriplet= last_red = image[i][width - j - 1];  // This is an alternative pointer to the struct
BYTE* plast_red = &image[i][width - j - 1].rgbtRed;
```

and then use the pointers and a temporary variable which swap:

```
BYTE temp = *plast_red;
*plast_red = *pfirst_red;
*pfirst_red = temp;
```

Comment: Oh wow, seems more complicated than I thought. Makes sense though. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @abbanator you are welcome, if you like the answer and it answers your question you could mark it as accepted.